# I have gparted on my Ubuntu system but when I try to add gpart to it, it says there is not installation candiadate

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a corrupt file system that I am trying to repair with gparted. When I go to the "rescue" option in gparted, it says to install gpart. Shen I give the command

```
sudo apt install gpart
```

it says there is no installation candidate and that the package is referred to by another package. How can I get gpart?

I have booted from an Ubuntu image on a flash drive.

Comment: `gpart` is in the Universe repository.  Universe isn't enabled by default on the Ubuntu live installers.  `sudo add-apt-repository universe` should enable Universe.